# Change CharSet field of DllImportAttribute at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, unicode, pinvoke, dllimport

What I am trying to do is to be able to compile against two versions of a native DLL using the same method in the managed code.

For example, this would be my native method signature:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyClass::NativeFoo(const TCHAR* txt)
```

It compiles to accept a `char*` in one build and a `wchar*` in another.

The pInvoke signature looks like this:

```
[DllImport("Native.dll")]
private static extern void NativeFoo(string txt);
```

To be able to control the `CharSet` used by the pInvoke call, I am using the following method:

```
internal static void SetUnicodeMode(bool state)
{
    MethodInfo m = typeof(ManagedFoo).GetMethod("NativeFoo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    object[] atts = m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DllImportAttribute), false);
    DllImportAttribute dllatt = (atts[0] as DllImportAttribute);
    dllatt.CharSet = state ? CharSet.Unicode : CharSet.Ansi;
}
```

And I am calling this method at startup of the managed assembly (at which point I know if I need to use unicode or mbcs).

The method throws no exceptions, but it also does not change the `CharSet` used by the pInvoke call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach. Just declare two separate externs and decide which one to call at runtime

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, that's a reasonable workaround, and I'll probably do just that. Nevertheless the issue aroused my curiosity and I'd like to find out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Is it possible that the marshalling code is generated at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to work.  The CLR will create its own instance of the [DllAttribute], it will not use yours.  The values used for the attribute constructor arguments are stored in the assembly metadata, you cannot change that data.

The only reasonable way to move ahead is to use *two* declarations with different names.  Use the EntryPoint property of the attribute to map them to the same exported function.  It is otherwise very unclear what trigger you'd use to pick one over the other, the actual DLL is of course going have to be different as well.  This is extremely unusual, a TCHAR is only to be a different type of character when you rebuild the DLL with different compiler settings.  Particularly the UNICODE and _UNICODE #defines.  With no conceivable reason left for still using 8-bit characters, or TCHAR, that was the previous century.  A sanity check is highly indicated here.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer. I realize the requirement must sound strage so allow me to explain. I am compiling against multiple versions of an SDK. Some of these use Unicode, while others use MBCS. As a result, for each version of the SDK I will have a different unmanaged dll, but I will only have one managed assembly.

Comment: I've gone ahead with two declarations as suggested and it is working fine.